# R Mechanism behind input$table_rows_all from DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

i have a question about input$table_rows_all from DT package.
I have actually noticed that while using it my code/table is rendered more then one time(?). At first the table with 0 rows and then accordingly to filtered rows --> **my actual App is very complex, therefore i loose on time during this operation**.

Here is an easy example of what i mean:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
dataTableOutput("table1"),
dataTableOutput("table2"))

server <- function(input, output) {

output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
datatable(iris,filter="top")})

output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
data <- iris[input$table1_rows_all,]
str(data)
datatable(data)})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

After running this code we can see in the console this output:

```
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num 
 $ Sepal.Width : num 
 $ Petal.Length: num 
 $ Petal.Width : num 
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num 
 $ Sepal.Width : num 
 $ Petal.Length: num 
 $ Petal.Width : num 
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I have tried to look for any documentation but could not find anything. Any explanation would be helpfull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `req` prevents this behaviour:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  dataTableOutput("table1"),
  dataTableOutput("table2"))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris,filter="top")
  })

  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$table1_rows_all) ## run the following code only if table1_rows_all is truthy
    data <- iris[input$table1_rows_all,]
    str(data)
    datatable(data)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

# 'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

My understanding of `reactives` is that whenever something changes the `oberserver/render*` functions are invoked. I assume this is also the case at the startup.

For `observeEvent` you have even a parameter `ignoreInit` which prevents the observer to fire on init.

Answer (score 1):

While @thothal proposes a solution, here I'd like to answer the question directly. When you initialize your app, DataTables are just empty `<divs>` which are filled with content only when user opens the app. To verify this behavior, run your example, open it in browser and then (in firefox) right-click -> View Page Source. For explanation, see [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).

Let's see this in your app -- I have added some 'debug prints' and a js alert that will help:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  shiny::tags$script(
    "$(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function(event) {
      alert('Connected to the server');
    });"
  ),
  dataTableOutput("table1"),
  dataTableOutput("table2"))

server <- function(input, output) {

  #  this ignores input$table1_rows_all being NULL and runs only when there is a value
  observeEvent(
    input$table1_rows_all,
    {
      print("observeEvent called")
      print(input$table1_rows_all)
    }
  )

  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    print("renderDataTable -- table 1 called")
    datatable(iris,filter="top")
  })

  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    print("renderDataTable -- table 2 called")
    if (is.null(input$table1_rows_all)) {
      print("input$table1_rows_all is NULL")
    }
    data <- iris[input$table1_rows_all,]
    datatable(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = FALSE))
```

Run the app and open it in browser. You see that session is initialized and each `renderDataTable` has run once. As mentioned earlier, they are just empty placeholders by now and variable `input$table1_rows_all` just does not exist at this point -- that's why you have 0 rows.

```
[1] "renderDataTable -- table 1 called"
[1] "renderDataTable -- table 2 called"
[1] "input$table1_rows_all is NULL"
```

Click ok to proceed. The following lines are printed subsequently:

```
[1] "renderDataTable -- table 2 called"
[1] "input$table1_rows_all is NULL"
[1] "observeEvent called"
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28
 [29]  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56
 [57]  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84
 [85]  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112
[113] 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140
[141] 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
[1] "renderDataTable -- table 2 called"
```

My understanding of what is going on here is the following:

1) for some reason `renderDataTable` for `table2` function is called. However, `input$table1_rows_all` is still `NULL`.

2) `table1` actually gets rendered (i.e., rows are loaded) so `input$table1_rows_all` becomes available. This results in print from `observeEvent` and another call from `renderDataTable` for `table2`.